# Поддомен в папку домена

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Подскажите возможно ли это реализовать...
У нас есть ресурс site.com и ext.site.com...
необходимо чтобы ext.site.com открывался на site.com/ext...
Реально ли это посредством mod_rewrite?

Для чего нужно, что бы вес сайта ext.test.com уходил на test.com для поисковых систем...

Answer (score 1):

> чтобы ext.site.com открывался на site.com/ext.
>   +
>   что бы вес сайта ext.test.com уходил на test.com для поисковых систем.

Стандартный 301 redirect - подставьте свои домены и прочее...

*301 редирект с домена на папку на другом домене*

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^si-te\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.ru/si-te/ [R=301,L]
```

*UPD по комменту

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ext.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/ext/ [R=301,L]
```

или `https` - как у Вас там нужно.

Comment: не работает совсем... под si-te понимается  поддомен и директория ( в нашем случае ext?)

Comment: Значит, Вы что-то не так делаете. Добавил ваши домены из вопроса в ответ

Comment: У нас site.com и ext.site.com два независимых ресурса, поэтому вопрос, возможно ли запросы к site.com/ext брать с ext.site.com и выводить на site.com/ext

без интеграции одного движка в другой, только по средством .htaccess и mod_rewrite

Comment: При 301 все обращения будут перенаправлены на новый адрес, согласно инструкциям. Ваш вопрос по интеграции не получается понять мне - редирект и предназначен для перенаправления обращений с одного одреса на другой - домены, папки, конкретный адрес конкретной старницы.